# MVC asp.net Load Image from network folder

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am working on an ASP.NET Razor website. 
Now in my View I want to Display an Image which is stored on an published folder in our network.

I save the absolute Path to the Image as an string like:

```
\\my-server\publishes_folder\folder1\img00001.jpg
```

How can I display the Image in the View? When I inspect the sourcecode I see that the path so the Image ist relative outgoing from my Server. 
For information, there are about 35.000 different Images in this folder, so copying them in my project isn't a solution. But for every image I get the path as string.
What can I do? Any surgestions?

Comment: you can use the html tag <img> like in any html file and the attribute href. There is any reason why you can't do that?

Comment: I tryed it, but then he didn't resolve the absolute path. I got something like "webserver/myabsolutepath".

Comment: what about the permissions of your application? the app can access that folder? did you check that?

Comment: I would say virtual directory would be first attempt. If that proves too problematic, create an action that would act as a proxy to that directory (e.g. `Image/Get/foo.jpg` is a Get action on the Image controller that yields an image (that was retrieved from the network directory))

Answer (score 0):

Your image is on a server that the client won't be able to access. As you don't want to copy the images and assuming you have access to the web server, you could create a virtual directory and point that to your server. That will then create a path that is relative to your site, allowing you to include images like:

```
<img src= "@Url.Content(Model.ImagePath)" alt="Image" />
```

However, virtual directors do come with security implications.

[How to: Create and Configure Virtual Directories in IIS 7.0](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763173.aspx)